# How to loop through an array on Apify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, web-crawler, apify

I am crawling Sainsbury’s, this is my start URL: `https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/meat-fish/all-chicken-44?fromMegaNav=1#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=310864&parent_category_rn=13343&top_category=13343&pageSize=36&orderBy=FAVOURITES_ONLY%7CSEQUENCING%7CTOP_SELLERS&searchTerm=&beginIndex=0&hideFilters=true`

I am looking to have the category, subcategory and subsubcategory display with every single item's price, title and image src on the page.

My current code returns (in JSON) product title, price and image. It also returns the category, subcategory and subsubcategory of the page I am crawling. I am looking to return the category beside every product title, price and image, and am unsure how to set up a loop to do this.

```js
function pageFunction(context) {
// called on every page the crawler visits, use it to extract data from it
var = context.jQuery; var result = []; (".article").each( function() {
result.push({

        title : $(this).find(".productNameAndPromotions:eq(0) a:eq(0)").text(),
        price : $(this).find(".pricePerUnit:eq(0)").text(),
        image : $(this).find('img').attr('src'),
        
        category : $(this).find('span:eq(1)').text(),
        subcategory : $(this).find('span:eq(3)').text(),
        subsubcategory : $(this).find('span:eq(5)').text(),
        subsubsubcategory : $(this).find('span:eq(7)').text()
     
   });
  });
return result;}
```

This is what my code returns

[JSON Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j6gd.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you add a description here of what your code returns?

Comment: Code returns (in JSON) product title, price and image. It also returns the category, subcategory and subsubcategory of the page I am crawling. I am looking to return the category beside every product title, price and image, and am unsure how to set up a loop to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put category and subcategories out of each scope.

```
function pageFunction(context) {
    // called on every page the crawler visits, use it to extract data from it
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var results = [];
    var categoty = $('category selector').text().trim();
    var subCategory = $('subCategory selector').text().trim();
    var subsubcategory = $('subsubcategory selector').text().trim();
    var subsubsubcategory = $('subsubsubcategory selector').text().trim();
    (".article").each( function() {
        results.push({
            title : $(this).find(".productNameAndPromotions:eq(0) a:eq(0)").text(),
            price : $(this).find(".pricePerUnit:eq(0)").text(),
            image : $(this).find('img').attr('src'),
            category : categoty,
            subcategory : subCategory,
            subsubcategory : subsubcategory,
            subsubsubcategory :subsubsubcategory
        });
    });
    return results;
}
```